# Add text to UItextField without erasing old text

Tags: ios, objective-c, textfield

I have an `UItextField`, and I want to display the content of an array in it.
So I tried something like that (and then I realised it obviously wouldn't have worked):

```
for (NSInteger i=0; i<myArray.count; i++) {
    [self.myTextField setText:myArray[i] ];
}
```

So, as you may guess, this code just displays the last element of my array in my text field.

My question: is it possible to edit the content of a text field, without erasing the content already present ?

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: In the future, try doing a little extra research first. You can tell it's an insanely simple/basic solution that's probably out there in many many places when you get 4 answers within 32 seconds of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[self.myTextField setText:[[self.myTextField text] stringByAppendingString:myArray[i]]];
```

Comment: No problems. Don't forget to mark it as answer for other people. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. 
One way to do this using your existing method is

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {

    self.myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.myTextField.text, myArray[i]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't debug this so forgive me if it doesn't work.

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {
    self.myTextField.text = [self.myTextField.text stringByAppendingString:myArray[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting to your field every iteration, append the array contents to a mutable string and set the field to that string at the end. You may need to append spaces or new lines as needed if you want to format it differently.

```
NSMutableString *arrayContentsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {
    [arrayContentsString appendString:myArray[i]];
}

[self.myTextField setText:arrayContentsString];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to append text to the existing text, you can do this:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {
    [self.myTextField setText:[self.myTextField.text stringByAppendingString:myArray[i]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSArray has a method called `componentsJoinedByString`' which returns an NSString object that is the result of interposing a given separator between the elements of the array.

```
NSString *string = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
[self.myTextField setText:string];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with fast enumeration it will be faster:-

```
for (NSString *str in  myArray)
{
    self.myTextField.text = [self.myTextField.text stringByAppendingString:str];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift answer:

```
self.myTextField.text = self.myTextField.text?.stringByAppendingString(" ★")
```